# get method not displaying the data on browser and put showing error on postman

Tags: javascript, json, api, get, postman

I'm creating an API with JS. While using the get method I'm not receiving the JSON data from the `./personal_data.js` file. It's only displaying closed braces as response.

I'm attaching the code and output below. Any suggestions might be helpful.

```js
const express = require('express');
const personal_data = require('./personal_data');

const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000');
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ Message: 'API is Working' }); // show messsage on serv
});
app.get('/personal_data', (req, res) => {
  res.json(personal_data); // send employee json file
});
app.post('/personal_data',(req,res)=>{

    res.send('post request')
})
```

[json file with data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NRX2.png)

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpUhX.png)
[Post man](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqTrE.png)

Comment: Have you tried to use `module.exports` instead of `module.export`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're exporting your data correctly. Use `module.exports = ...` instead of `module.export = ...` in your `personal_data.js`. Don't forget to restart your server once it's updated.

Check this sandbox where I show you the difference: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/module-export-vs-module-exports-yhcte)

Comment: could you please check the error on my post method?

Comment: Looks good to me. Updated my sandbox with your post route and seems to be working fine.